# How to apply Text to Columns using 3-character separator?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to separate a column of data in Excel, with the numbers following the " - " in a second column. The data looks like this:

```
Cabin-Fever - 28,315
CANBRICKYYJ - 11
Capstone - 170,049
CB Brick Builds  - 41
CCX-Custom-Works - 53
```

I cannot separate based only on the dash ("-") as some of the names are hyphenated. The Text to Column wizard allows only a 1-character separator, so I cannot use the " - ", and various formulae that I have found online using LEN, RIGHT, LEFT, and SEARCH (or FIND) all return NAME or VALUE errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MID(FIND()):

```
=--MID(A1,FIND(" - ",A1)+3,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott! This formula works as I had described. However, I have just realized that my original request was incomplete, as I was hoping that the first column would have the numbers removed. The end result should look like:

A               B
Cabin-Fever      28,315
CANBRICKYYJ      11
Capstone              170,049
CB Brick Builds     41
CCX-Custom-Works    53

How can I edit your proposed formula to "cut" the dash and numbers and paste them to the B column, rather than only copy/pasting them? Thank you again!

Comment: At this point the best thing to do would be to mark this correct as it answered the question, and ask a new question.